# Why do I suddenly get an error when trying to send a google search using a MSXML2.XMLHTTP object?

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest, windows-7, office-2007

I'm using this script I compiled to get details about the documentaries that I watch. Based on the filename, I get a documentary name, I then compile a google search string, I search google, get google's response, open the correct link from it, and get the data. This used to work until a few days ago. Today, I tried running my script, and I get an error right at the very beginning, while calling the function that does the google search. This is the function:

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
End Function
```

"url" is compiled based on different criteria. Right now it is:

> [https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=site:docuwiki.net+++"secrets+in+our+dna+"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=site:docuwiki.net+++%22secrets+in+our+dna+%22)

The error triggers on the ".send" line. The error is:

> Run-time error '-2147024891 (80070005)': Access denied.

If I then click on debug and try to run the script again (from the current point), I get another error:

> Run-time error '2147467259 (80004005)': Unspecified error.

I don't think I made any changes to the system between the last time it worked and now. Haven't installed anything, no updates, nothing. I should mention that I'm on a fairly old laptop, using MSOffice 2007 under Windows 7.

Here's a minimal reproducible example. This causes the aforementioned error (that it wouldn't have a couple of weeks ago).

```
Public Function getHTTP(ByVal url As String) As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        Debug.Print url
        .send
        getHTTP = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With
End Function
Sub testing123()
    Dim a, URL1
    URL1 = "https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=site:docuwiki.net+bbc+""beautiful+minds+"""
    a = lcase(getHTTP(URL1))
End Sub
```

Comment: You might not have made any changes, but Google does from time to time. What exactly is the `url` that errors? Does it work if you `Debug.Print url` and copy that URL into a browser? Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates the issue so we can reproduce it.

Comment: Note that [Windows 7 support ended on January 14, 2020](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-support-ended-on-january-14-2020-b75d4580-2cc7-895a-2c9c-1466d9a53962) and you are using it in the Internet. Good luck! Windows does not receive any security updates anymore.

Comment: Thank you, Peh. I edited my original post to include an example that triggers the error. All the urls that i generate inside the script work when pasted in chrome. I know I'm pushing my luck with win 7, but newer versions of windows move really slowly on my computer. I'll also edit the code to constitute a minimal reproducible example, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Your example runs through for me and I get status 200 OK. No issues or errors here. So I suspect you did that several times and got banned by Google? Google doesn't like automated scripts that are not using their API.

Comment: i accidentally solved it :) i realised i was only testing my urls in chrome, and i tried to test them in internet explorer. i opened IE (something i hadn't done in quite a while) and upon accessing the link i got, instead of a google search, one of those pages asking me to accept google cookies and stuff like that. i agreed, then the link was opened, then i ran my script again and it worked fine. could you recommend what to do with my question?

Comment: may I ask what was wrong?

Comment: i pressed enter before my previous reply was finished, and it was posted. i have edited it now.

Comment: Since the answer might be useful for future readers I recommend you to write your solution as an answer here below the comment section (see [answer]). After one day (I think) you can accept your own answer as solution to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the problem was caused by not having opened Internet Explorer in a long time. When I tested my URLs, I only did so in Chrome. When I tried to paste the same URL in IE and access it, I got one of those cookie confirmation pages. After agreeing to the cookies and closing IE, I tested the script again and it worked like it used to.